# How to filter the string pattern in extjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string, extjs

I do have me.innerHTML variable which stores all data into it in currently opened editor. If I inspect element, then for some html tags like href, img src it gives me local path of "file:///C" which should be removed even before saving the document.

The output image of following code:

[http://imgur.com/z6lmDFE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsRYn.png)

Visit https://jsfiddle.net/8juqcLjn/  for fiddle

In the output i need to remove the whole line "file:///C:\blah\blah\blah"

For this I need to form a Regular Expression

Here is the code snippet

```
Ext.EventManager.on(this.doc.body, {
        'paste':  function(){
        var me = this;
        var strText = "";
        var replaceText = "<br></font>";
        setTimeout(function() {
        strText = me.innerHTML; 
        strText = strText.split(replaceText).join("</font>");
        strText = strText.split("<p style=\"margin: 0in 0in 0pt;\"><span style='font-family: \"Arial\",\"sans-serif\"; font-size: 10pt;'>&nbsp;</span></p>").join(" ");
        strText = strText.split("<span style=\"text-decoration: none;\">&nbsp;</span>").join("");
        strText = strText.split(": 1em;").join(": 1px;");
        selfEditor.setValue(strText);
        }, 0);
        setTimeout(function() {
            selfEditor.doc.focus();
            }, 500);
    }
    });
```

Comment: can you add a [fiddle](http://fiddle.sencha.com)?

Comment: Your code isn't running, please use the link I gave you to run a proper ExtJS Environment